# Symfony2 Assetic: duplicates combined content of JS files in dev environment

Tags: symfony, duplicates, assetic

I have set up assets in my `config.yml`:

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

On twig template JS files are loaded:

```
    {% block javascripts %}
        {% javascripts output="assets/js/app.js"
            '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'
            '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/bootstrap.min.js'
            '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/thirdparty/bootstrap-select.min.js'
            '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/forms.js'
             %}
            <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
    {% endblock %}
```

**The issue is**: In dev environment there are 4 separate requests to these files, but each one is combined with others (what should be done ONLY in prod environment):

[image]

[image]

Seems like some misconfiguration, but have no idea what exactly.

P.S. In prod environment eveything OK - there is only 1 request for combined file.

P.S.S. Symfony version is 2.8.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by reinstalling `symfony/assetic-bundle`.

Still have no idea what was wrong.